# Priorizar linha na Consultas sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Em um Resultados com 2 campos exatamente iguais, como fazer que só mostre linhas que a coluna prioridade  esteja marcada como 1

> ```
> id   |   origem   | destino  | daia_inicio  | data_fim   |  valor  | prioridade
> 01   |   Galeão   |  Barra   | 01/01/2018   | 31/12/2018 |  400,00 | 0
> 02   |   Galeão   |  Barra   | 10/01/2018   | 20/02/2018 | 1000,00 | 1
> 03   |   Rio      |  Barra   | 10/01/2018   | 20/02/2018 | 2000,00 | 0
> 04   |   São paulo|  Barra   | 10/01/2018   | 20/02/2018 | 4000,00 | 0
> 05   |   Brasilia |  Barra   | 10/01/2018   | 20/02/2018 | 8000,00 | 0
> ```

**Resultado esperado**: ( Só mostrar linha 2 pois se encontra com a prioridade marcada )

> `02       Galeão      Barra     10/02/2018  -  20/02/2018   1000,00`

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 3):

Você terá que utilizar a cláusula `WHERE` na sua consulta para filtrar os resultados.

Exemplo:

`SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela WHERE prioridade = 1`

Veja a documentação do [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: My bad, já removi e alterei um "extra" :) min 6 chars -.-

Comment: Agora sim! Valeu!

Comment: Parceiro isso não resolve o meu caso. assim só mostra linhas com prioridade = 1 ,,, mais e as restantes que não tem  prioridade deixara de ser mostrada... pensa  o seguinte.... em uma lista de 10 linhas sendo que 2 linhas são iguais, mais uma das iguais tem prioridade.. então a consulta devera retorno 9 porque entre 2 repetidas ela devera excluir aquela que não tinha prioridade

Comment: Então informe exatamente o que você precisa no campo de pergunta, brother. Da maneira como escreveu: *"como fazer que só mostre linhas que a coluna prioridade esteja marcada como 1"*, eu e outras pessoas entendemos que o seu problema era esse. Dê mais detalhes...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode compara a tabela com ela mesma para obter a máxima prioridade:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE t.prioridade = (SELECT MAX(t2.prioridade)
                         FROM tabela t2
                        WHERE t2.origem = t.origem
                          AND t2.destino = t.destino)
```